# Cassandra 3.6.0 bug: StackOverflowError thrown by HashedWheelTimer on Connection.release

Tags: cassandra, stack-overflow, datastax

When running some inserts and updates on Cassandra database via the java driver version 3.6.0, I get the following StackOverflowError, of which I am showing here just the top, but it repeats the last 10 rows endlessly.
There is no mention of any line in my code, so I don't know what was the specific operation that invoked this.

```
    2018-09-03 00:19:58,294 WARN  {cluster1-timeouter-0} [c.d.s.n.u.HashedWheelTimer]  : An exception was thrown by TimerTask.
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4604)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4568)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4604)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4602)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Start.match(Pattern.java:3461)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.search(Matcher.java:1248)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.find(Matcher.java:664)
        at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2549)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
        at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.BusyConnectionException.<init>(BusyConnectionException.java:29)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$ResponseHandler.<init>(Connection.java:1538)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.write(Connection.java:711)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.write(RequestHandler.java:451)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.access$1600(RequestHandler.java:307)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution$1.onSuccess(RequestHandler.java:397)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution$1.onSuccess(RequestHandler.java:384)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1355)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:398)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1024)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:866)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:689)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:48)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool$PendingBorrow.set(HostConnectionPool.java:755)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool.dequeue(HostConnectionPool.java:407)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool.returnConnection(HostConnectionPool.java:366)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.release(Connection.java:810)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution$1.onSuccess(RequestHandler.java:407)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution$1.onSuccess(RequestHandler.java:384)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1355)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:398)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1024)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:866)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:689)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:48)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool$PendingBorrow.set(HostConnectionPool.java:755)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool.dequeue(HostConnectionPool.java:407)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool.returnConnection(HostConnectionPool.java:366)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.release(Connection.java:810)
```

I do not use any UDTs.

Here are the keyspace and table creation code:

```
session.execute(session.prepare(
          "CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS myspace WITH REPLICATION = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1': '3'}  AND DURABLE_WRITES = true;").bind());

session.execute(session.prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myspace.tasks (myId TEXT PRIMARY KEY, pointer BIGINT)").bind());

session.execute(session.prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myspace.counters (key TEXT PRIMARY KEY, cnt COUNTER)").bind());
```

This is the prepared statement that I use:

```
PreparedStatement quickSearchTasksInsert = session.prepare("INSERT INTO myspace.tasks (myId, pointer) VALUES (:oid,:loc)");
```

The code that reproduces the issue does the following:

1. Runs about 10,000 times the method writeTask() with different values such as the following example rows which are selecteed from a SQL database:

   05043FA57ECEAABC3E096B281A55356B,   1678192046
   5DE661E77D19C157C31EB7309494EA89,   3959390363
   85D6211384E6E190299093E501169625,   3146521416
   0327817F8BD59039069C13D581E8EBBE,   2907072247
   D913FA0F306D6516D8DF87EB0CB1EE9B,   2507147331
   DC946B409CD1E59F560A0ED75559CB16,   2810148057
   2A24B1DC71D395938BA77C6CA822A5F7,   1182061065
   F70705303980DA40D125CC3497174A5D,   1735385855
2. runs the setLocNum() method with some Long number.
3. Loop back to (1) above.

   ```
   public void writeTask(String myId, long pointer) {
       try {
         session.executeAsync(quickSearchTasksInsert.bind().setString("oid",myId).setLong("loc", pointer));
         incrementCounter("tasks_count", 1);
       } catch (OperationTimedOutException | NoHostAvailableException e) {
         // some error handling ommitted from post
       }
    }

   public synchronized void setLocNum(long num) {
       setCounter("loc_num", num);
   }  

   public void incrementCounter(String key, long incVal) {
       try {
         session.executeAsync(
             "UPDATE myspace.counters SET cnt = cnt + " + incVal + " WHERE key = '" + key.toLowerCase() + "'");
       } catch (OperationTimedOutException | NoHostAvailableException e) {
         // some error handling ommitted from post
       }
   }

   public void decrementCounter(String key, long decVal) {
       try {
         session.executeAsync(
             "UPDATE myspace.counters SET cnt = cnt - " + decVal + " WHERE key = '" + key.toLowerCase() + "'");
       } catch (OperationTimedOutException | NoHostAvailableException e) {
         // some error handling ommitted from post
       }
   }

   public synchronized void setCounter(String key, long newVal) {
       try {
         Long prevCounterValue = countersCache.get(key);
         long oldCounter = prevCounterValue == null ? readCounter(key) : prevCounterValue.longValue();
         decrementCounter(key, oldCounter);
         incrementCounter(key, newVal);
         countersCache.put(key, newVal);
       } catch (OperationTimedOutException | NoHostAvailableException e) {
         // some error handling ommitted from post
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Can you add some steps in order to be reproduced?

Comment: I just use two small tables: The first has counter field and I decrement it and then increment it. The second table has 2 columns: TEXT and BIGINT and I insert rows into this table. I use executeAsync for all these operations. The code manages to run at about 55,000 successful operations per second for 20 seconds until the above error occurs.

Comment: If you don't have any UDTs, I think that could only be a Cassandra driver bug.

Comment: It would be good if you can put some keyspace/table definitions, some sample data and some code that you run. This will help anyone who tries to reproduce to have a very close scenario to yours and not making incorrect assumptions.

Comment: I have just added code and data to the original post.

Comment: What is your cassandra version? From the title seems like Cassandra 3.6, but when you describe the issue, it seems like you are using the java driver 3.6.0. Or you are using Cassandra 3.6(released in june 2016) with java driver 3.6(released in august 2018)? Or you have managed to reproduce on several Cassandra 3.x/3.0 versions with 3.6 driver? Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry for the mixup. The Cassandra server version is 3.11.1 and the client java driver version is 3.6.0. The issue is obviously in the client.